# Calling a method from AppModel class from its child or Controller

Tags: php, class, cakephp, inheritance

Hello this is my AppModel.php Class

```
<?php
App::uses('Model', 'Model');
class AppModel extends Model{


    static public function message()
    {
        return 'this is a message';
    }

}
```

and I have my model User.php

```
<? 
class User extends AppModel {

}
```

and my controller UsersController.php

```
class UsersController extends AppController
{
 public function index()
    {
        $this->layout ='main';
}

}
```

My question is, how can I call method message() from its AppModel Class in UsersController or at least in my model Users?

Comment: have you tried $this->User->message(); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it like you do with any static method

```
AppModel::message();
```

Though, I suggest not using it as static. In your controllers and definitely in your models you will have already an instance of a model that extends the AppModel. So if you change

```
/*static*/ public function message()
{
    return 'this is a message';
}
```

then you can call it in controllers like

```
$this->User->message();
```

and in the user model with

```
$this->message();
```

And while we're on it, change it to `protected` so only it's children can use the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, your comment has helped me solve my problem and confusion

However when I change the method to protected function message(){...}

I get this error Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'message' at line 1

Comment: Ah, that means that your model is not recognizing that function and is interpreting it as SQL. Where and how are you calling it?

Comment: I am calling it in my usercontroller.php inside  public function index()
    {  echo  $this->User->message(); }